# Very anomalous behaviours by C++ compiler

Tags: c++

I have the following code. In the function `xyz(int from, int to, int i)`. I am printing the value of `i` and `i*2+1`. But I am getting unexpected output with `i = 1` and `i*2+1 = -1`. 
The function `xyz2()` is exactly the same except that I have uncommented a dummy function call and I am getting the expected output with `i = 0` and `i*2+1 = 1`. Please see [the output](http://ideone.com/oT83pJ) as I have explained it. Also I would mention that I get the same output on my local machine.

Why is this happening?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    long long arr[2];
    long long xyz(int from, int to, int i);
    long long array[200000];
    long long xyz2(int from, int to, int i);

    long long foo(){return 141;}

    int main(){
        int n=2;
        arr[0] = -4;
        arr[1] = 5;
        xyz(0, 1, 0);
        printf("\n\n");
        xyz2(0, 1, 0);
        return 0;
    }

    long long xyz2(int from, int to, int i){
        if(from==to){
            return arr[to];
        }else{
            int mid = (from+to)/2;
            array[i*2+1] = xyz2(from, mid, i*2+1);
            array[i*2+1] = foo();
            printf("%d %d\n", (i*2)+1, i);
            return 100000;
        }
    }

    long long xyz(int from, int to, int i){
        if(from==to){
            return arr[to];
        }else{
            int mid = (from+to)/2;
            array[i*2+1] = xyz(from, mid, i*2+1);
            //array[i*2+1] = foo();   // The above function xyz2 gives the 
                                  //correct results on uncommenting this line
            printf("%d %d %d\n",array[i*2+1], (i*2)+1, i);
            return 100000;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you start using parentheses?

Comment: %d is for an int, not a long long. Fix that to make things work as expected.

Comment: I think some one has to lift the hood and look at the assembly code generated out of this maddnes.

Comment: Strangely enough coliru gives a completely different output [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b11369f82371d380).

Comment: @Jefffrey: Actually, my version of gcc produces the same output as coliru. OP should add his compiler.

Comment: @Zeta Which is ideone's compiler, probably.

Comment: Why aren't you using C++ library and facilities instead of C's ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
printf("%d %d %d\n",array[i*2+1], (i*2)+1, i);
```

The first data argument is a `long long`. You need to change your format string to match:

```
printf("%lld %d %d\n",array[i*2+1], (i*2)+1, i);
```

The reason you're getting weird behaviour when the wrong conversion specification is used is because the behaviour is undefined:

> *C99 §7.19.6.1/9* If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

This comes from the specification for `fprintf`, which `printf` is defined in terms of. The C99 standard is normative for C++11.

Answer (score 0):

This line in xyz2(..):

```
  printf("%d %d %d\n",array[i*2+1], (i*2)+1, i);
```

is NOT the same as this line in xyz(..)

```
  printf("%d %d\n", (i*2)+1, i);
```

Changing the commented out line changed the result as follows:

**With Line Commented**

> -4 1 0
>
> 1 0

**With Line Uncommented**

> 141 1 0
>
> 1 0

I don't seem to be getting any strange output (I think) using XCode 5....but I **AM** getting warnings about the format of the printed string:

```
printf("%d %d\n", (i*2)+1, i);
```

should be

```
printf("%lld %d\n", (i*2)+1, i);
```

Using long long requires a special print format, I believe.  This could be the problem...